# Storing a user ID with the session id

Tags: go, redis, redis-cluster

I am saving sessions in redis database (not in memory, actually DB).

I want to store something with the session to be able to track the users sessions and be able to limit amount of sessions each user can have.

I have sign up, sign in and sign out working.

On sign it, it checks if they have a valid session, if not it will authenticate the user and then create a session and add values to the sessions.
When they sign out it will delete the session.

When I check the Redis db I see:

**KEYS '*'**

```
"session_QPEOONJ25OG4HGWCN4Y556VGUN26V7IIASOYLGBVPZSPKO2B3P7FENYYDLPRWV2IBJK4RNANLCYANGMN7UUDG6DJ4NZG7XZBSFW3LWI"
```

Here is my sign in function.

```
func signIn(c echo.Context) error {

    ctx := c.Request().Context()
    collection := mg.Db.Collection("users")

    // validation code removed for convenience 

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(existingUser.HashedPassword), []byte(signInUser.Password))
    if err != nil {
        return c.String(http.StatusNotAcceptable, "Incorrect password")
    }

    store := redisSessionInstance.Store

    session, err := store.Get(c.Request(), "session_")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed getting session: ", err)
    }

    // checks if session exists or is new one
    if session.IsNew {
        session.Values["id"] = existingUser.ID.String() // ID of user from mongodb
        session.Values["role"] = existingUser.Role

        // Save session
        if err = session.Save(c.Request(), c.Response()); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("failed saving session: ", err)
        }
    }

    return c.String(http.StatusAccepted, "Signed In!")
}
```

As you can see I get the users ID and role among other things.

I want to be able to limit the amount of sessions each user can have open at any time.
I also want to be able to know what sessions are for each user in the Redis Db and be able to delete the sessions per user. (basically some way to tie each user to their session)

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list for storing sessions of an user. you can limit the number of sessions by checking length with `LLEN <key>` in advance.

you can query all the sessions in the list with `LRANGE <key> 0 -1`

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, how would I store a list and how would it work with my current solution? Thank you

Comment: I have currently change it so the session stores a userSessionID to the token. This means that for all sessions that are allocated to a specific user they have the value of userSessionID. How can I store this via the redis store using the session package which is: github.com/rbcervilla/redisstore/v8